# Перевод string в массив int 1 байт С++

Tags: c++

Нужно перевести строку в массив int 1 байт.
Работает с int и int16_t

```
#include "Poco/DateTime.h"
#include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using Poco::DateTime;
using Poco::DateTimeFormatter;

void main()
{
    DateTime now;
    now.makeUTC(10800);
    auto value = DateTimeFormatter::format(now,"[%m - %d %H:%M:%S:%F]");
    std::vector<int> ints;
    ints.reserve(value.size()); 
    std::transform(std::begin(value), std::end(value), std::back_inserter(ints),
        [](char c) {
        return c;
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ints[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output: `91 49 49 32 45 32 50 50 32 49 52 58 48 51 58 51 56 58 57 55 52 56 54 54 93` 
           Если заменить `std::vector<int8_t> ints;`
Output: `[ 1 1   -   2 2   1 4 : 1 5 : 2 2 : 1 3 0 5 7 3 ]`

Comment: Вообще-то строка - это и есть массив однобайтных величин :) Что вообще значит - "int 1 байт"?

Comment: Вот что мне нужно `int8_t buffer[] = {0,27,128,0,0,0,3,172,0,17,91,49,49,45,49,48,32,50,51,58,48,58,48,58,48,93,0 };`

Comment: Объясните тупому, откуда у вас сразу в строке нулевой символ? Что это за магические числа? Откуда их нужно брать? У вас идут какие-то непонятные вещи, потом [11-10 23:0:0:0]. Вам это нужно?

Comment: Это я написал пример финального буффера. Код из топика составляет только его часть.

Answer (score 1):

Тип  `int8_t` обычно определяется как алиас для типа `signed char`. Поэтому если вы хотите вывести эти значения как неотрицательные целые числа, то вам следует написать

```
for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>( static_cast<unsigned char>( ints[i] ) ) << ' ';
}
```

Потому что в противном случае вызывается перегруженный оператор `operator <<` для типа `signed char`, который выводит символы на консоль вместо кодов символов.

Также не ясен смысл использования алгоритма `std::transform` , когда вы используете на самом деле обычное копирование.

Вы можете написать просто

```
std::vector<uint8_t> ints( std::begin( value ), std::end( value ) );
```

Но и этом случае при выводе на консоль, вам надо приводить элементы вектора к целочисленному типу, отличного от типа `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char`, как, например, к  типу `int`

Например,

```
for ( int x : ints ) std::cout << x << ' ';
```

Comment: int8_t не может быть псевдонимом char поскольку стандарт требует для него signed integer type, к которым char не принадлежит.

Comment: @GreenDragon Это опечатка. Я исправил на signed char.^)

Comment: @GreenDragon char вполне может иметь тот же диапазон значений, что и signed char, а наличие int8_t и вовсе не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Что у вас не так - связано с тем, как `cout` выводит `unsigned char`. Вот вывод вашего `std::vector<int8_t> ints;`

```
vector<unsigned char> v;
string s = "Hello, Dolly!";

for(auto c: s) v.push_back(c);

for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    cout << hex << int(v[i]) << ' ';
}
cout << endl;
```

Просто с приведением к int...